# Atualização ortografica com REGEX - Javascript backend

Tags: javascript

tudo bem ?

Preciso fazer uma atualização de algumas cidades que estão meio bagunçados no sistema , onde existem registros so com maiúsculo e minúsculo quero deixar tudo parametrizado . 
Pensei em algo do Tipo o usuário cadastra da forma que quiser aí o sistema se encarrega de consertar após o update.

Alguém pode me dar um help??

Comment: Complicado isso. Teria que desenvolver um código bem inteligente para que o sistema saiba como corrigir, e mesmo assim teria que ter uma lista de todas as cidades como referência. E se vc tiver uma lista, fica sem sentido tentar fazer isso. Seria melhor que o usuário selecionasse a cidade a partir da lista.

Comment: function retiraAcento(palavra){
 
 var com_acento = 'àáâãäèéêëìíîïòóôõöùúûüÀÁÂÃÄÈÉÊËÌÍÎÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜçÇñÑ´`^¨~';
 var sem_acento = 'aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuuAAAAAEEEEIIIOOOOOUUUUcCnN     ';
 var nova='';
 
 
 for(i=0;i < palavra.length;i++) {
  if (com_acento.indexOf(palavra.substr(i,1)) != -1) {
   nova+=sem_acento.substr(com_acento.indexOf(palavra.substr(i,1)),1);
  }
  else {
   nova+=palavra.substr(i,1);
  }
 }
 return nova.toUpperCase();
}

Comment: Algo assim ,mas ai seria necessário  tratar numa string paralela o valor do campo jogar no current , mas não consegui ainda .rsrsrs

Comment: Entendi, vc quer apenas tratar os acentos?

Comment: os acentos e se Upper case e lower case , ex: SAO PAULO para São Paulo

Comment: o problema é como o sistema vai saber que o "a" de "São" tem o til `~`...

Comment: rsrsrs , mas deve haver um jeito .. Brigadão

Comment: Como o @dvd citou, é muito complicado fazer esse tratamento, você levaria muito tempo para realizar cadastro de regras sem a garantia iria suprir 100% a necessidade.